# RxJava order of unsubscribe

Tags: android, rx-java, reactive-programming

I am wondering if there is any possibility to control the order of `unsubscribe` callbacks, lets assume I have two instances of `google api`
the `client` and `location provider`, the `location provider` requires `client` in order to request updates. Both of them need to call either `disconnect` or `removeCallbacks` on `unsubscription`, this is done easily using `Subscriber.add()`. But the problem is that when chained using `switchMap` for example:

```
Observable.just(GoogleApiClient)
.switchMap(client -> Observable.just(LocationApi(client))
```

Everything seems to work fine until the `unsubscription`, because it first unsubscribe the GoogleApiClient and then the observable inside `switchMap` which requires client, resulting in no removal of callbacks since client is no longer connected. Is there any workaround to this problem? Lets assume we need this `Observable` of `GoogleApiClient` in different places so we can not create the client in the same `OnSubscribe` as `LocationApi`

Comment: You'd probably have to implement your own Subscription container to do this. See [here](http://akarnokd.blogspot.co.uk/2015/05/operator-concurrency-primitives_19.html).

Comment: Thanks, I have looked at the post, but don't think this is what I would need, because there is still one subscription but with some inner - the switchMap one which is unsubscribed after the outer one